# clearInterval not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am calling function on click when autoswitch = true function also calls setInterval and set autoswitch value to false by clicking again calling clearInterval  which doesn't work.

Need some help

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var speed = 500;
  var autoswitch = true;
  var autoswitch_speed = 4000;

  //add active class
  $('.slide').first().addClass('active');

  //hide slides
  $('.slide').hide();

  //show first slide
  $('.active').show();

  // Click next to show next slide
  $('#next').click(function() {
    nextSlide();
  });

  //Onclick go to prev slide
  $('#prev').click(function() {
    prevSlide();
  });

  //play auto slide show
  $('#playBtn').click(function() {
    if (autoswitch === true) {
      var setIntr = setInterval(nextSlide, autoswitch_speed);
      autoswitch = false;
    } else {
      clearInterval(setIntr);
      autoswitch = true;
    }
  });

  // next slide function
  function nextSlide() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');

    if ($('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
      $('.slide').last().addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
    }

    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
  }

  // Prev slide function        
  function prevSlide() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');

    if ($('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
      $('.slide').last().addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
    }

    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
  }
});
```

Comment: `var setIntr` is bound by the `if` statement. Make the variable public to use it in `else` statement too.

Comment: I think it is working if you move `setIntr` to global scope

Comment: because you declare it in `if`  block so it can not access in `else` block\

Comment: As a note: always make sure that the indentation of your code is correct, not only to help others to understand your code, but it will also help you to keep it maintainable.

Comment: @Developer107 no it is not bound to the if statement, `var` binds to the function scope. `let` binds to the block scope.

Comment: There is no error in this code *per se*, the error is elsewhere . And please don't do `if (autoswitch === true) ` for your own explicitly declared Booleans, the `if (autoswitch) ` will suffice.

Comment: @BekimBacaj the problem is not somewhere else the problem is the`var setIntr = setInterval(nextSlide, autoswitch_speed);` because for each click it will be a _new_  `setIntr` (the lifetime of `setIntr` is only for the click).

Comment: Isn't that the original idea of the op?

Comment: @BekimBacaj The OP want to clear the interval at a second click, but the interval id that is returned by `setInterval` won't be available in the second click, so at the point where the OP calls `clearInterval(setIntr);`  the `setIntr` is `undefined`.

Comment: it can't be undefined, because the new set interval will be invoked .

Comment: @BekimBacaj first click: `autoswitch` is `true`, so first block of the `if` is evaluated, `var setIntr = setInterval(nextSlide, autoswitch_speed)` and `autoswitch` is set to `false` (`autoswitch` is declared in the outer scope). Second click:    `autoswitch` is `false`, so second block the `if` is evaluated, but for `clearInterval(setIntr);`, the `setIntr` is `undefined` because `setIntr` is declared in the callback itself.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare **setIntr** outside of the **click** function.
So you could set it at the top of the **ready** function.

I have gone and fixed your code here: https://snippetbox.xyz/9eb54a2a1f52dc1f5d40/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var speed = 500;
  var autoswitch = true;
  var autoswitch_speed = 4000;
  var setIntr;

  //add active class
  $('.slide').first().addClass('active');

  //hide slides
  $('.slide').hide();

  //show first slide
  $('.active').show();

  // Click next to show next slide
  $('#next').click(function() {
    nextSlide();
  });

  //Onclick go to prev slide
  $('#prev').click(function() {
    prevSlide();
  });

  //play auto slide show
  $('#playBtn').click(function() {
    if (autoswitch === true) {
      setIntr = setInterval(nextSlide, autoswitch_speed);
      autoswitch = false;
    } else {
      clearInterval(setIntr);
      autoswitch = true;
    }
  });

  // next slide function
  function nextSlide() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');

    if ($('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
      $('.slide').last().addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
    }

    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
  }

  // Prev slide function        
  function prevSlide() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');

    if ($('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
      $('.slide').last().addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
    }

    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are defining setIntr as a local variable to that function.  Once it goes out of scope and is called again you no longer have a handle on that interval.  You need to define the var out of scope somewhere.  I would make it a global, but I'm sure there might be better ways

Answer (score -1):

you just have to add variable "**setIntr**" out side the if condition as like below:

```
$('#playBtn').click(function() {
  var setIntr;
   if (autoswitch === true) {
    setIntr = setInterval(nextSlide, autoswitch_speed);
    autoswitch = false;
    } else {
     clearInterval(setIntr);
     autoswitch = true;
    }
  });
```

As you have declared "setIntr" in If Condition which is not accessible in else, so if you want to use it in else as well then you have to declare it out side the if or globally.

**EDITED:** 
you are trying to set the value in one condition and checking in else. in this case you must have to declare the "**setIntr**" as global variable.

so the working code should be like the following:

declare "**setIntr**" globally in document.ready

then use the below code:

```
$('#playBtn').click(function() {
 if (autoswitch === true) {
   setIntr = setInterval(nextSlide, autoswitch_speed);
   autoswitch = false;
 } else {
  clearInterval(setIntr);
  autoswitch = true;
 }
});
```

Comment: The explanation `As you have declared "setIntr" in If Condition which is not accessible in else` is wrong. `var` declares variables for the whole function. [MDN: var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Comment: @t.niese, if you check the question you will get what i am telling here.. i am asking to check the questioner that he had declared the varibale in if condtion and he is trying to access it in else.. which is not possible.. then i post my first answer.

Comment: Worked, Amazing Thanks A lot.

Comment: @Spark, if it works for you, please don't miss to accept the answer.. :)

Comment: The first part of your answer (the one before the _EDITED_) is completely wrong. Because the declaration of variables using `var` is hoisted to the top of the function block,  your code (the first on in your answer)  is identical to the one in the question. Your second code will work, but using `setIntr` without any declaration will write it to the global scope and I highly discourage  from doing this, it would be better to declare it within the scope of the callback of the ready function.

Comment: @t.niese, what is your problem bro.. please read the whole answer before commenting anything, if you check i carefully i have written that you have to declare the variable globally in docuemt.ready block. i really disappointed from your for such type of behaviour.

Comment: My main concern is not about your second half (which is inaccurate but ... somehow ok), it is about the **first** part of your answer:`you just have to add variable "setIntr" out side the if condition as like below: [...code...] it will solve your problem.` no it won't solve the problem, because it is identical to what the OP already has, so this is completely wrong. `you have to declare it out side the if or globally.` as long as outside the `if` is in the same function block it won't make a difference, this is also misleading.

Comment: @t.niese, after that i had updated my answer as well by adding "you are trying to set the value in one condition and checking in else. in this case you must have to declare the "setIntr" as global variable." hope this clear the confusion.